# Meaning of "wird eigener Vision nicht gerecht"

Tags: meaning

> Obama wird eigener Vision nicht gerecht.

What does this sentence mean? Does it mean "Obama is not upright to his vision"?

Also, is "eigener Vision" dative or genetive here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase is `etwas/jemandem gerecht werden` with `etwas/jemandem` being dative. It means to meet some expectations/standard/conditions ….

`eigener Vision` means his own vision. The dropping of `seiner` in this situation is typical newspaper style.

So this sentence means, that Obama doesn't meet (the expectations of) his own vision.